# Listbox Help wanted (simple script)

Tags: listbox, autohotkey, msgbox

I am not an expert but try to figure it out about ~6 hours now,
I have a selection window with 2 items, and whatever what i choose it say i choose No1 item. Later on i replace nr1, nr2, with actions if the selections could working. Please help! I assume i use wrong code at MyListbox1.

```
Gui, Add, ListBox, vMyListBox1 gMyListBox1 w100 r10
{
    GuiControl,, MyListBox1, Item1|Item2
}
Gui, Show
return

MyListBox1:
if A_GuiEvent <> DoubleClick
    return
GuiControlGet, MyListBox1, %Item1%
GuiControlGet, MyListBox1, %Item2%
IfMsgBox, %Item1%
MsgBox, MsgBox You entered 1
    return
IfMsgBox, %Item2%
MsgBox, MsgBox You entered 2
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Gui, Add, ListBox, vMyListBox1 gMyListBox1 w100 r10, NotePad|x
Gui, Show
return

MyListBox1:
if A_GuiEvent <> DoubleClick ; If not double click stop
    Return
GuiControlGet, MyListBox1 ; Get current value of MyListBox1 variable
If (MyListBox1 = "NotePad") ; If MyListBox1 contains NotePad
    Run, NotePad.exe
Else If (MyListBox1 = "x") ; If MyListBox1 contains x
{
    Send, !{Esc} ; Need to switch back to previous application since GUI is in focus and you would send the data to your own GUI
    Sleep, 100 ; Wait a little while, so that the other application can be in focus
    Send, x ; You could have used Send, %MyListBox1%, since MyListBox1 contains x
}
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```

Comment: Thank You Sir! Its very kind you helping me! its working, selection make properly. But how can i work with the selected item? I mean (for exmple) for Item1 run notepad.exe, for Item2 send a X letter on keyboard?

Comment: Exactly what im looking fo! Thank you for your detailed answer, i am really greatfull!

Comment: Peter, As you seem to be new to this site, could you close the question by clicking on the white check mark next to the answer. This way the question is marked as answered and I get credits.

Comment: Okey, Thanks!, I can't give You vote, because i dont have enough reputation to do that, but big THUMBS UP!

Comment: The g-label is critical for this. Very useful.